# How to make vim indent matching paren instantly

Tags: vim

For example, when I have this

```
function foo() {
  bar()
  }
```

After I input the last curly brace, vim will unindent it so it matches the indentation level of this function like this:

```
function foo() {
  bar()
}
```

However, after I input the curly brace, there is a small lag before vim auto-matches the indentation. Vim first highlights the opening paren, goes back to closing paren, and then unindents it. Since this behaviour looks like `pi_paren`, I tried turning it off by `:NoMatchParen`, but nothing changed.

How can I remove this lag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off that built-in behavior via

```
:set noshowmatch
```

or alternatively try to reduce the `'matchtime'` value.